# How can I get instant CPU load values?

Tags: server, cpu-load

I have made a server-client application in which based on CPU usage and load conditions it serves a file request to user.

I am using `/proc/loadavg values` for this . But this utility gives values averaged out over at least 1 minute.

I want values averaged out over much lesser time like 1 second or 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

How about parsing the output from `mpstat` from the `sysstat` package? You can get statistics for each processor and set the interval (below is for 2s interval).

Sample output:

```
$ mpstat -P ALL 2
Linux 3.5.0-19-generic (ubuntu)     11/30/2012  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

08:34:28 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
08:34:30 AM  all    1.01    0.00    1.26    0.00    0.00    0.13    0.00    0.00   97.61
08:34:30 AM    0    2.50    0.00    1.50    0.00    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00   95.50
08:34:30 AM    1    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
08:34:30 AM    2    1.01    0.00    3.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.98
08:34:30 AM    3    0.50    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.00
```

Alternatively, you could implement the algorithm yourself.  Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29#CPU_Load_Computation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748136/how-is-cpu-usage-calculated).

Another way to do it would be to monitor the difference in idle time vs other usage time in `/proc/stat` at defined time interval and calculate the load based on that. [Here's more info on /proc/stat](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm).

Comment: Can you indicate where you installed cpustat from? It is not installed by default or located in the common repositories. thx

Comment: Whoops... I have no idea. Found a different software that's better documented too: `mpstat` in the sysstat package. I'm going to edit the answer to get rid of cpustat